# Does the existence of the monopole in a 2+1D $U(1)$ gauge theory require the gauge field compact?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, magnetic-monopoles, lattice-gauge-theory

I find the monopole is allowed in a 2+1D compact $U(1)$ gauge theory in lattice (Hermele, PRB 69,064404 (2004)), there the gauge field $A$ is also compact and takes value in $[0,2\pi)$, so there is a branch cut structure in gauge field $A$ which relates to the monopole. And also in deconfined quantum criticality context (Senthil, PRB 70,144407), the monopole is relevant in compact theory but it is surpressed in noncompact theory.

In the chapter 8 of David Tong's gauge theory lecture notes, the topological current, topological charge in a 2+1D maxwell theory are given as
$$S_{Maxwell}=\int d^{3}x(-\frac{1}{4e^2}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+A_{\mu}j^{\mu}),\\B=F_{12},E_{i}=F_{0i},\\J^{\mu}_{topo}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho}F_{\nu\rho},\\Q_{topo}=\int d^{2}x J^{0}_{topo}.$$ Compact is not mentioned in this note.

**Question:**

1. Does the existence of the monopole in a $U(1)$ gauge theory require the gauge field compact?
2. What is the compact theory mean? Compact gauge group or compact gauge field?
3. What does the topological symmetry relating to the $Q_{topo}$ broken mean? Is that the monopole condensing?

Comment: I feel you may have confused yourself by saying "compact" too many times in a row. There are two things which may be compact, the spacetime, and the gauge group. These are separate things. I note that $U(1)$ is already compact. The non-compact alternative would be and $\mathbb{R}$ gauge group. There is no sense in which a field can be "compact." Can you clarify what it is you're asking about?

Comment: @RichardMyers The gauge field is usually defined in $[0,2\pi)$ in lattice gauge theory context, say page 5 in Hermele, PRB 69,064404.

Comment: That is because it is an element of the Lie algebra. If the Lie group is $U(1)$, the Lie algebra is parametrized by the angles of a circle. Anyway, my answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/617965/278763) question may answer yours.